# Finding limit of function $f$, given limit of expression with $f(x)$.

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I have the following exercise:

> If $\lim\limits_{x \to 1}{\frac{f(x) - 8}{x - 1}} = 10$, find $\lim\limits_{x\to1}{f(x)}$.

I'm not sure how to go about this specific exercise, nor exercises similar to it.

---

**Update** *(In response to @DanielFischer's comment.)* $^*$

$\lim\limits_{x \to 1}{[\frac{f(x) - 8}{x - 1}]} = 10$

$\frac{\lim\limits_{x \to 1}{[f(x) - 8]}}{\lim\limits_{x \to 1}{[x - 1]}} = 10$

$\lim\limits_{x \to 1}{[f(x) - 8]} = 10\lim\limits_{x \to 1}{[x - 1]} = 0$

$^*$ As @DanielFischer later pointed out, my method was incorrect.

Comment: Start with finding $\lim\limits_{x\to 1} \bigl(f(x) - 8\bigr)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer -- See update. I'm not sure whether this is what you meant; if so, I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @SirJony I don't recommend multiplying both sides of the equation by $0$.

Comment: @mrob -- Yes, good point. :)

Comment: Not quite, in your second line you have $\frac{0}{0} = 10$, that's not legit. But $$\lim_{x\to 1} \bigl(f(x)-8\bigr) = \lim_{x\to 1} \biggl(\frac{f(x)-8}{x-1}\cdot (x-1)\biggr) = \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{f(x)-8}{x-1}\cdot \lim_{x\to 1} (x-1) = 10\cdot 0 = 0.$$ And $\lim\limits_{x\to 1} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to 1} \bigl((f(x)-8) + 8\bigr) = \lim\limits_{x\to 1} (f(x)-8) + \lim\limits_{x\to 1} 8 = 0 + 8$.

Comment: @DanielFischer -- So, I was just lucky in getting the same result? But, now with this result, how do I proceed? Do I pull $-8$ out of the limit and move it to the RHS, resulting in $\lim_{x\to 1}{f(x)} = 8$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define: $$g(x) = \frac{f(x) - 8}{x - 1} \quad\quad \text{for} \;\;x \ne 1$$

Then the premise can be written as: $$\lim_{x \to 1}g(x) = 10$$

But $\;f(x) = (x-1)g(x) + 8\;$ for $\;x \ne 1\;$ from the definition of $\;g(x)\;$ so:

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) & = \lim_{x \to 1} \big((x-1)g(x) + 8\big) \\
 & = \lim_{x \to 1} (x-1) \cdot \lim_{x \to 1} g(x) + 8 \\
 & = 0 \cdot 10 + 8 \\ & = 8
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I need a small clarification: When solving for $f$, you "moved" $x-1$ over to the other side; can you explain why this was valid, but the way I did it (as @DanielFischer pointed out) was false?

Comment: Your line had the actual $\lim_{x \to 1} (x-1)$ in the denominator, and that limit is an actual $0$. In my answer, the definition of $g(x)$ is only required to hold for $x \ne 1$ since it's only used in determining a limit when $x \to 1$, in other words the denominator $(x-1)$ is never evaluated *at* $x=1$.

Comment: OK, thanks. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that in order to get a limit on the left-hand side, you need an indeterminate form since $x-1\to 0$. That means $f(x)-8 \to 0$. Otherwise, the limit does not exist.

Thus $f(x)\to 8$.

Comment: I'm fairly new to limits, so I'm not precisely sure what you mean by "indeterminate form" and why. If you could elaborate on your explanation, that would be great.

Comment: @SirJony https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form. They should be listed in your calculus textbook, but essentially, indeterminate forms sometimes appear when your function is not continuous at the point to which you are taking a limit. If you formally plug in the value, you get something like $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, which is meaningless (hence indeterminate). If the numerator in your problem weren't $0$ as well, then the "form" would be like $\frac{1}{0}$, which converges to $\pm \infty$ or neither, and certainly not $10$.

Comment: OK, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)-8=\frac{f(x)-8}{x-1}*(x-1) \to 10*0=0$  for $ x \to 1$