# Verifying Exercise: Given limit-equation's RHS, find limit of $f(x)$.

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, proof-verification

*I recently posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2019152/finding-limit-of-function-f-given-limit-of-expression-with-fx), and received a satisfactory answer. Afterwards, I tried a similar exercise myself. Here it is:*

---

### Exercise

> If $\lim \limits_{x \to 0}{\frac{f(x)}{x^2}} = 5$, find the following limits.
>
> 1. $\lim \limits_{x \to 0}{f(x)}$
> 2. $\lim \limits_{x \to 0}{\frac{f(x)}{x}}$

---

### Solution

**1.**

- Let $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x^2}$
- Solving for $f(x)$: $f(x) = x^2 g(x)$
- $\lim \limits_{x \to 0}{f(x)} = \lim \limits_{x \to 0}{x^2 g(x)} = \lim \limits_{x \to 0}{x^2}\lim \limits_{x \to 0}{g(x)} = 0 \cdot 5 = 0$

**2.**

- Let $h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$
- $h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x} = \frac{x^2 g(x)}{x} = x g(x)$
- $\lim \limits_{x \to 0}{\frac{f(x)}{x}} = \lim \limits_{x \to 0}{h(x)} = \lim \limits_{x \to 0}{x g(x)} = \lim \limits_{x \to 0}{x}\lim \limits_{x \to 0}{g(x)} = 0 * 5 = 0$

---

### Answer

**1.** $$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}{f(x)} = 0$$

**2.** $$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}{\frac{f(x)}{x}} = 0$$

---

Are my answer correct? If not, where'd I go wrong in my solution?

Comment: It's fine for me. Could be shorter if you can use asymptotic analysis (mainly use big O notation and the rules of computation thereof).

Comment: Whatever you're suggesting means, no thanks. :) I'll stick to beginner-calculus knowledge. However, for others' sake (and me in the future), maybe you can post an answer using your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The proof is quite fine.

However you can make it shorter using  *asymptotic analysis* if it's in your tool-box:

The hypothesis implies $f(x)=O(x^2)$ (actually, it is stronger), hence

- $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$ since $x^2$ does.
- $\dfrac{f(x)}x=O\Bigl(\dfrac{x^2}x\Bigr)=O(x)\to 0$.